# Dynamically add multiple kendo dropdown lists in custom template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm investigating if it is possible to dynamically add kendo dropdown lists to a custom template in a grid?

What I'm trying to do is have 3 dropdown lists in one column based on a condition or 2 dropdown lists in the one column if the other condition is met.

Is there a way to do this in Kendo? I do apologise for lack of code, but I have no starting point and wanted to investigate if it is even possible.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'if' in the template and render the dropdownlists conditionally as for example it is explained in [this article about templates](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview). Another option is to use the [edit event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/edit) and inject the desired widgets dynamically depending on your conditions.